# Additional arguments to Ajax callback function using Sajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, sajax

I've got the following situation:

```
// callback function for the asynchronous call
function get_data_cb(z, arg1) {
    // do something
}

function foo() {
    var n = 1;
    // get_data is a server-side function triggered by the AJAX call, 
    // client only has the wrapper function with the same name
    get_data(get_data_cb);  // 1
}
```

My question:

At 1), how do I pass variable n all the way to get_data_cb? I'm using sajax_export() on the server-side ajax function to produce a client-side wrapper.

Comment: Does n have to go to the back end, is n always an integer?

Comment: Nah, it's just an example. Although it will be an int in my case. P.s. it's not going to the back end, it's going to the callback.